# How to make a confirmation page that shows content of a form in HTML/PHP?

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm making an html/php form for my database. The form sections are divided in nav-tabs (bootstrap). The tab titles are `Personal Information`, `Status`, `Accounts`, `Projects`, and `Confirm`. How do I display all the info from the first 4 tabs in the confirm tab so the user can review before submitting?

Edit: From what I understand, I would have to write all the fields in the confirm tab and enter the id's to display them? Here is a sample of code:

```
<div class="tab-content">
   <fieldset class="tab-pane active" id=pers_tab">
      <form>
         First name:<br>
            <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
            <!-- followed by last name, email, phone, etc. -->
      </form>
   </fieldset>
</div>
```

So in my `<fieldset class="tab-pane" id="conf_tab">` I would have to write something like `First name: firstname`? (Not sure about the syntax) I don't know if name and id work the same in this case...

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Share what exactly you have tried. Then we can help I hope

Comment: I've never done this before.. About a month ago all I knew was java. So honestly, I'm sort of lost. If someone could explain to me like I'm 5, that would be great. To answer your question, so far I have tried googling it, but didn't find what I needed.

Comment: Could you show us your current HTML code?
Have you already started processing your form results in PHP? If so, showing us what already exists might be helpful.

Comment: Sorry but then SO isn't right place for this kind of questions ("I need to do XYZ, can you suggest a tutorial really close to my needs or can you drive me step by step?"). That's why question has been downvoted and closed. It's not because people don't want to help you but because it's a very specific question limited to your own problem. Moreover answer may be pretty long and opinion based (then it won't help anyone else in future). First try to do it and feel free to come back with a more focused and specific issue!

Comment: How is it not going to help anyone in the future? If I knew how to do it, or found a solution myself, I wouldn't be asking. I thought the point of this was to help each other out.

Comment: And fyi there are plenty of other questions on here that are "I need to do XYZ can you suggest a tutorial or can you drive me step by step". PLENTY.

Comment: Could you be more precise about what you want to do? When the user submits the form, before save the fields into your database, you want to show him what he entered so that he can confirm them. Do you want to do it without reloading the page (in that case you'll have to use some JavaScript)? Or the page can be reloaded once, showing the field and a 'Confirm' button, and then when he clicks on 'Confirm' the page reloads again, saving the fields into the database and showing a success message 'You're informations have been saved'?

Comment: I wanted to load the form and display the input so the user can verify that the date they entered is correct. But i's ok, I changed the design. I'm just going to have a message popup when the user clicks submit asking the user to verify the input before finally submitting. I don't know why I was complicating it. Thanks anyways.

Comment: I do not think you were complicating it, if you want your website showing things in a way and not in another, it is always possible. :) And now that I have understood what you wanted, it doesn't seem too complicated (for the developer -as long as you are familiar with JS- and for the website's user) to me. The thing here is that your question was not very clear, and we did not have all the elements to answer it (that is why we asked you more informations, and wanted to know if you already tried something or if you were completely stuck, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case your want to try, I made something that, I hope, is what you wanted to do.

I used some JavaScript and jQuery library. (I have no idea if you are familiar with it or not. I tried to explain simply what I am doing, I recommand you to search for more informations about it and learn the basis. :) )
I assume your bootstrap template already includes `jquery.js` library.

**HTML**

```
<div class="tab-content">
  <!-- Tab containing the form -->
  <fieldset class="tab-pane active" id="pers_tab">
    <form id="my_form">
      First name:<br>
      <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname"><br>
      <!-- Other fields (lastname, email, etc.) -->
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="submit_btn">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </fieldset>

  <!-- Tab containing the confirmation infos -->
  <fieldset class="tab-pane" id="conf_tab">
    Please confirm your informations :<br />
    Firstname: <span id="confirm_firstname"><!-- Empty span for now, but we will put the firstname here. --></span><br />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="confirm_btn">Confirm</button>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit_btn').click(function() {
    // Triggered when the element with id 'submit_btn' is clicked.

    // Get the value of the field with 'firstname' id.
    var firstname = $('#firstname').val();
    // Put it as text in the element with 'confirm_firstname' id.
    $('#confirm_firstname').text(firstname);

    // Hide form tab and show confirmation tab
    $('#pers_tab').removeClass('active');
    $('#conf_tab').addClass('active');

    // Prevent the form from submitting
    return false;
  });

  $('#confirm_btn').click(function() {
    // Submits the form with id 'my_form'
    $('#my_form').submit();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your input. Helped a lot! However aside from not wanting to complicated things, another reason why I moved away from the nav tabs was because I realized that some of my sections are very small and it looks awkward when going from one tab to the next. E.g. Status only has 3 input fields whereas Accounts has 8. Again, thanks very much. This will still come in handy! :)